# displaying a numerical value relating to the dice image shown

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm fairly new to programming and for a uni project I have created a simple game where there are two payers who each have a die. The dice are then rolled and whoever has the highest number wins, simple.

The program works as expected but I want to add an extra textbox below the die which will display the numerical value of the image.

I believe the DisplayDice method assigns the value to the correct image, so do I need to somehow assign this to the textbox? and am I right in thinking that I can't assign an int to a textbox so do I need to use int.Parse?
here is my code;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Attributes
    // Values live for as long as the form is open
    Random _rnd = new Random(); // Random number generator
    string[] _diceImages;       // store names of all image files
    int[] _playerDice;          // Dice values for each player
    int _spinCount;             // Count of number of animation ticks

    const int NUMBER_OF_FACES = 6;      
    const int NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS = 2;
    const int PLAYER_ONE = 0;
    const int PLAYER_TWO = 1;
    const int NUMBER_OF_SPINS = 5;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _diceImages = new string[NUMBER_OF_FACES];      // _diceImages is set to the value given to NUMBER_OF_FACES
        SetupDiceImages();

        // One die per player, create dice
        _playerDice = new int[NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS];       // _playerDice is set to the value given to NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS
        ChangeDiceValue();

        DisplayDice();
    }

    // sets the correct dice image to the relevant value in the array
    // there are six faces on a die so the array needs six values, 0-5
    private void SetupDiceImages()
    {
        _diceImages[0] = "one.gif";
        _diceImages[1] = "two.gif";
        _diceImages[2] = "three.gif";
        _diceImages[3] = "four.gif";
        _diceImages[4] = "five.gif";
        _diceImages[5] = "six.gif";
    }

    // random number is generated to change the value displayed on the dice
    private void ChangeDiceValue()
    {
        // Generate random values between 0 and 5
        _playerDice[PLAYER_ONE] = RandomValue(NUMBER_OF_FACES - 1);     //random number generated for player 1
        _playerDice[PLAYER_TWO] = RandomValue(NUMBER_OF_FACES - 1);     //random number generated for player 2
    }

    // tells the program which number to display
    private void DisplayDice()
    {
        int diceValue;

        diceValue = _playerDice[PLAYER_ONE];        // Value thrown by player one
        playerDicePictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("../../Images/" + _diceImages[diceValue]);     // tells the program where to get the image for player 1's picture box

        diceValue = _playerDice[PLAYER_TWO];        // Value thrown by player two
        playerDicePictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("../../Images/" + _diceImages[diceValue]);     // tells the program where to get the image for player 1's picture box

    }

    // Generate random value between 0 and maxValue
    // including 0 and maxValue
    private int RandomValue(int maxValue)
    {
        return _rnd.Next(0, maxValue + 1);
    }


    // animation starts when the button is clicked
    private void throwDiceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _spinCount = 0;                 // Start counting again
        animationTimer.Enabled = true;  // Start the timer

    }

    private void FindWinner()
    {
        // Check values of dice here
        int player1Dice;
        int player2Dice;

        player1Dice = _playerDice[PLAYER_ONE] + 1;     // 0 To 5 hence + 1
        player2Dice = _playerDice[PLAYER_TWO] + 1;
    }

    private void animationTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeDiceValue();
        DisplayDice();

        if (_spinCount + 1 < NUMBER_OF_SPINS)
        {
            // Safe to implement the count
            _spinCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            // Stop animation now
            _spinCount = 0;
            animationTimer.Enabled = false; // Stop the timer
            FindWinner();
            // if statement is used to find a winner
            if (_playerDice[PLAYER_ONE] > _playerDice[PLAYER_TWO])  // if player one's die is greater than player two's
            {
                resultTxtBox.Text = ("Player 1 WINS!!!");           // this message is displayed if the above is true
            }
            else
            {
                resultTxtBox.Text = ("Player 2 WINS!!!");           // if the above is false then this message is displayed
            }
            if (_playerDice[PLAYER_ONE] == _playerDice[PLAYER_TWO]) // player one and two have the same number
            {
                resultTxtBox.Text = ("It's a DRAW!!!");             // if the above is true then this message is displayed
            }
        }

    }

}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated as it will also help me with a blackjack game that I am also trying to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in saying that you can't assign an int to a textbox, however, all objects in .NET have the "ToString()" function, so you can get the string value with:

```
Player1ScoreTextBox.Text = player1Dice.ToString();
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx)

Note that if you had a large dice count, or floats, or something else that you need formatted a specific way, you can pass ToString a formatting string. For example `ToString("F2")` formats as a fixed point number with 2 decimal places of precision, so 2.1 becomes 2.10.

The other strings can also be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can assign the text representation of a integer value to the text of a textbox like:

```
tbPlayer1Value.Text = diceValue.ToString();
```